# Airflow branch operator doesnt recognize my task groups

Tags: python, airflow

i have the following dag, it creates dynamic tasks within task groups, based on mng tables in snowflake.
the thing is, i cant seem to get the branch operator works with these task groups.
it is imported ok to airflow without issues, but when running i get an error that the branch operator doesnt know the task groups, like the ids are invalid. for some reason.
cant seem to see what am i doing wrong, will appreciate your help.
this is the error i get when running :

> [2023-11-23, 12:31:48 UTC] {cli_action_loggers.py:85} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: []
> [2023-11-23, 12:31:48 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 13407 for task branch_task ('branch_task_ids' must contain only valid task_ids. Invalid tasks found: {'load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg'}.; 2225105)
> [2023-11-23, 12:31:48 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

and this is my dag code  :

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
from pendulum import datetime,now
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from TNG_functions_Yoav import log_error_to_snowflake,log_elt_process_to_snowflake
import uuid
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
 


father_run_identifier = "{{ run_id }}" 
process_general = "DAILY"



@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    on_success_callback=lambda context: log_elt_process_to_snowflake(context, context['run_id'],process_general) ,
    default_args={
        'on_failure_callback': lambda context: log_error_to_snowflake(context, context['run_id'])
    })

def asaf_MNG_DAG_master_template_branching():
    
    def get_task_group_run_identifier(task_group_name, run_id):
        return f"{run_id}_{task_group_name}"
    
    area_variable = "XX"
    module_variable = "XXXX"
    layer_variable = "yy"
    action_variable = "LL"
    process_variable = "DD"
    clear_last_run_ind_variable = "True"
    
        
    @task
    def get_list_of_results(area, module, layer, action,process):
        hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_TNG')
        sql_query = f"SELECT QUERY FROM DER.GENERAL.queries WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG=TRUE AND LAYER = '{layer}' AND AREA = '{area}' AND MODULE = '{module}' AND ACTION = '{action}' AND PROCESS = '{process}';"
        results = hook.get_records(sql_query)
        return results

    @task
    def create_sp_list(result, run_identifier):
        query = result[0]

        if query[-3] == '(':
            sql = f"{query[:-2]}'{run_identifier}');"
        else:
            sql = f"{query[:-2]}, '{run_identifier}');"

        return sql
    
        
    @task
    def clear_last_run_ind(area, module,process):
        hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_TNG')
        sql_query = f"ALTER SESSION SET autocommit=True; CALL DER.GENERAL.SP_CLEAR('{area}' , '{module}' , '{process}') ;"
        results = hook.get_records(sql_query)
        
    @task
    def insert_last_run_ind(area, module, layer, action, process,father_run_identifier,run_identifier):
        hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_TNG')
        sql_query = f"INSERT INTO SANDBOX.PUBLIC.LOG(MOMENT, PID, AREA, MODULE, LAYER, ACTION,ROOT_PID, FATHER_PID, LAST_RUN_IND, PROCESS) SELECT current_timestamp,'{run_identifier}','{area}' ,'{module}','{layer}','{action}','{father_run_identifier}','{father_run_identifier}',TRUE,'{process}';"
        results_tag = hook.get_records(sql_query)


        with TaskGroup("load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg") as load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg: 

        run_identifier = get_task_group_run_identifier('load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg',father_run_identifier)
        
       
        if clear_last_run_ind_variable == "true":
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one = clear_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, process_variable)
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two = insert_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable, process_variable,father_run_identifier, run_identifier)
        else:
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one = DummyOperator(
            task_id="dummy_task_clear_last_run_ind"
        )
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two = insert_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable, process_variable,father_run_identifier, run_identifier)

        sp_list=get_list_of_results(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable,process_variable)
        
        # Log the list of values
        # log_list("sp_list", sp_list)

        sql_queries = create_sp_list.partial(run_identifier=run_identifier).expand(result=sp_list)

        
        SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id="load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg",
            snowflake_conn_id="SF",
            autocommit=True,
            sql=sql_queries
        )

        clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one >> clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two >> sp_list >> sql_queries

    area_variable = "DD"
    module_variable = "MMM"
    layer_variable = "SS20"
    action_variable = "HRD"
    process_variable = "DD"
    clear_last_run_ind_variable = "False"
 
    with TaskGroup("manual_tables_handle_duplicates") as manual_tables_handle_duplicates:

        run_identifier = get_task_group_run_identifier('manual_tables_handle_duplicates',father_run_identifier)

        if clear_last_run_ind_variable == "true":
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one = clear_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, process_variable)
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two = insert_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable, process_variable, father_run_identifier,run_identifier)
        else:
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one = DummyOperator(
            task_id="dummy_task_clear_last_run_ind"
        )
            clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two = insert_last_run_ind(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable, process_variable, father_run_identifier,run_identifier)

                
        sp_list=get_list_of_results(area_variable, module_variable, layer_variable, action_variable,process_variable)

        # Log the list of values
        # log_list("sp_list", sp_list)
        
        sql_queries = create_sp_list.partial(run_identifier=run_identifier).expand(result=sp_list)
        
        SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id="manual_tables_handle_duplicates",
            snowflake_conn_id="SF",
            autocommit=True,
            sql=sql_queries
        )
        clear_or_insert_job_att_part_one >> clear_or_insert_job_att_part_two >> sp_list >> sql_queries

    
    def decide_task(**kwargs):
        indicator = True  # Replace with your actual indicator value
        if indicator:
            return 'load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg'
        else:
            return 'manual_tables_handle_duplicates'
            
    
    
    branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch_task',
        python_callable=decide_task,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    
    branch_result = branch_task >> [load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg, manual_tables_handle_duplicates]

   
asaf_MNG_DAG_master_template_branching()
```